# Our Editing Help doesn't mention paragraph breaks

Tags: feature-request, editing-help

I just took a look at our [Editing Help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and noticed it makes no mention of the fact you need two line breaks for a paragraph break.

^ Like this. On the couple of SE sites I frequent, this seems to be the thing that *most commonly* trips up new users! Markdown ignores single lines, yet some new users don't know what to do about that. Some do nothing and just have their giant unbroken paragraph with ignored single line breaks, whilst others fill their post with `<br>`'s.

Please change the editing help to mention paragraph breaks at the beginning!

Comment: That is more or less standard... even with typewritten text.

Comment: @vonbrand Not really. Word and Notepad don't ignore your single linebreaks, and Word is happy to double-space your paragraphs from that single linebreak. If it's standard, that knowledge apparently hasn't caught on.

Comment: Ugh, yes.  Every time I have seen `<br />` used it just made a mess...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not Markdown that trips them up. It's that they're stuck in a word processing mind frame. Where paragraphs all join hands with indentations used to mark out when a paragraph starts.

It's a long held convention that when displaying paragraphs on websites you have a clear line spaced between the chunks of the text[.](http://www.impressivewebs.com/typesetting-paragraphs-web-pages/)

That they are actively ignoring the in-your-face live preview of the text as they write it is not going to be fixed by having an extra line in the formatting help that they weren't going to look at in the first place.

Comment: The ones who fill their posts with `<br>`'s as a solution to having line breaks apparently looked at it.

Comment: Looked at what? Putting in raw `<br>` tags is not a Markdown help guide

Comment: ... wow, okay, I must not have looked very hard at that section. I suppose this is less of an issue than I thought: it _does_ appear to only mention single line breaks in the editing help, but I haven't seen people actually using the double-space-for-br markdown.